# Configure Nginx to use cherrypy framework

Tags: nginx, cherrypy, uwsgi

I'm looking to use Nginx as the server and CherryPy framework on a linux server. I'm not looking to use Nginx as a reverse-proxy. I am moving away from PHP to python and i have a lot of cherrypy apps.

CherryPy wiki states that "CherryPy can be a web server itself or one can launch it via any WSGI compatible environment" I do not want to use the server part of cherrypy just the framework.

Does anybody know how to configure Nginx WSGI to use CheryPy?

Answer (score 3):

You can use uwsgi for serve the cherry application.
check this link:
http://nileshgr.com/2012/08/27/getting-cherrypy-working-with-uwsgi